# Converting list of Numpy ND Array to list of int

Tags: pandas, numpy

I wanted to find the index number for a specific float for which I ran the following code:

```
RELIANCE = pdr.get_data_yahoo('RELIANCE.NS', start='2023-02-01', end='2023-12-06')
RELIANCE.reset_index(inplace=True)
close_REL = RELIANCE['Close'].values
first_25DH = max(close_REL[25-25:25+1])
first_ds25dh = 25-int(np.where(RELIANCE['Close'][25-25:25+1] == first_25DH)[0])
```

This code was successful. However, when I try to achieve the same effect with a for loop, I get an error. This is the for loop I used:

```
# Creating a column for 25 day high
high_25D = []
for j in range(RELIANCE.shape[0]):
    if j < 25:
        high_25D.append(0)
    else:
        high_25D_j = max(close_REL[j-25:j+1])
        high_25D.append(high_25D_j)
RELIANCE['25D_high'] = high_25D

#
days_since_25DH = []
for j in range(RELIANCE.shape[0]):
    if j < 25:
        days_since_25DH.append(0)
    else:
        index_of_high_j = int(np.where(RELIANCE['Close'] == high_25D[j])[0])
        days_since_j = j - index_of_high_j
        days_since_25DH.append(days_since_j)

RELIANCE['Days since 25 day high'] = days_since_25DH
```

The error is as following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [163], line 6
      4     days_since_25DH.append(0)
      5 else:
----> 6     index_of_high_j = int(np.where(RELIANCE['Close'] == high_25D[j])[0])
      7     days_since_j = j - index_of_high_j
      8     days_since_25DH.append(days_since_j)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I can pass the code without `int()` but then I get a column where 25 row onwards, the element is an numpy.ndarray object. I would prefer the elements to be int objects.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example of your input and the expected output, it's likely possible to get rid of the loops.

Comment: `int(where(...))` only works when the `where` returns only one index.  Sounds like you get 2 or more. print `index_of_high_j` without the int so you clearly understand.

Comment: look at `RELIANCE` as constructed in the first loop.  Don't make assumptions about what's happening in the loops.  Verify!  We can't recreate your data.  You have to lokk yourself.

Comment: `np.where()[0]` returns a int dtype array..  Add a `tolist()` to make list.  `int()` only works if the array has one element.